# Forcing Categories in Publish Form

Tags: control-panel, forms

Using EE 2.5.5. I have a products channel with three category groups associated. How do I insure at least one category from each group is selected when the user adds or edits a product entry? Is there some form validation mechanism I missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the very useful [Category Field](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/category-field) addon.

From the Devot:ee description: "This field type allows you [to] organize your category groups as you would any other custom field type anywhere on your publish entries form."

You could create one "Category Field" field for each of your 3 category groups and make these fields required in the channel field settings, which I believe would accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the link Dylan. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Dylan: The 1.4.1 version did NOT respect the Required Field setting. I contacted Nuno Albuquerque, the developer; he responded right quick, and made the mod overnight. It's now available on github at https://github.com/NAlbuquerque/Category-Field-for-EE/tree/dev; but he'll be uploading it to devot:ee very soon. Just want to say how impressed I am with this community.

Comment: Hey guys, the latest version is up on Devotee and in the github master branch. https://github.com/NAlbuquerque/Category-Field-for-EE

Answer (score 3):

The [**BW Required Category**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/bw-required-category) addon will do the trick to makes categories required for specified channels.

Comment: Thanks for the link Anna_MediaGirl. I'd vote you up, but I don't have enough StackExchange juice yet.

Comment: Get working on that rep:)

Comment: Disappointed that rep from other StackExchange properties don't count here. (Not that I have oodles elsewhere either, but at least I could vote and such.) But will do.

Comment: They want people to gain rep by subject which is why it doesn't transfer.